# Phone gap ajax call fails when debug=false

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a problem with ajax call using phone gap. Excatly when i'am in debug mode everything work great but after switch to debug fals when i want put my app to android store then ajax fails. Hers code :

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "Lead Info"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>LEADInfo</name>

    <description>

    </description>

    <author >
        FASTDATA Team
    </author>
    <icon src="fa-cogs.png"   />
    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <!--
        Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
        <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
    -->
    <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.2.0' />

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />



    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:

        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
    <!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />


   <access origin="*" />


    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

And Function :

```
function log_in() {

    window.login_data = $("#login_form").serializeArray();
    window.username = login_data[0].value.toUpperCase();
    window.password = login_data[1].value;
    if (window.password == "" && window.username == "") {
        window.username = "a";
        window.password = "a";
    }

    var serwer_url = window.serwer;
    var index = serwer_url.indexOf("/");
    index = index + 1;
    window.header = serwer_url.substr(0, index);
    window.rest_url = serwer_url.substr(index + 1);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        url: window.header + window.username + ":" + window.password + "@" + window.rest_url + "/rin/mob_leady?resultsPerPage=100",
        processData: true,
        data: {},
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: load_start(),
        success: function (data) {
            window.test = data;
            console.log("autoryzowano");
            $("#login_error").css("display", "none");
            $("#leeds-content").load('auth_app.html');
            $("#leeds-content").css("display", "block");
            $("#login").css('display', "none");
            $("#contact_info_load").remove();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("nie autoryzowano");
            $("#login_error").css("display", "block");
            $("#password").val('');
            $("#username").val('');
            $("#contact_info_load").remove();
        }
    });
}
```

So i'am using Basic auth user input the domain adress when he want to login and get mob leads [information type] . Then input username and password and after that function send ajax call for url https://username:password@userdomain.com
On debug true it is  work correctty but on debug false its returning  ajax error. In this moment i cant get the message error. If i get this message i will add it. Somebody knows why its crash on debug false ?

My index.html head :

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">-->

    <!--fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hind-font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ubuntu-font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_styles.css">
    <script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

    <title>Aplikacja Leadinfo</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-2">
</head>
```

I try to use Content policy meta tag but its not working for me maybe i do some mistake.

Today i get a ajax call error :
status 0
ready state 0
responseText undefind

Comment: Can you also post at least the `head` section of your index.html?  I'm curious as to what your Content-Security-Policy meta tag looks like.

Comment: @SimonPrickett I add a head. I try use Content-Security-Policy meta tag but its not working for me maybe i do some mistake and finally i deleta this tag. Could you give me example wchich allow all source from cross domains ?

Comment: @SimonPrickett
Today i get a ajax call error :
status 0
ready state 0
responseText undefind

Comment: @SimonPrickett i Add :    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src *;
    style-src * 'unsafe-inline';
    script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
    media-src *; img-src * data:;
" /> and nothings change